# Stop Script Tags But Allow Others

Tags: php, html

Okay so I have a bit of a dilemma. I'm working on my own forum. On the topic pages I am using `htmlspecialchars()` as I want to stop people entering the `<script></script>` tags and entering something malicious and it redirects the page elsewhere. However, I want to be able to display text in italic if the text inputted is surrounded by `<i></i>` tags. When the user submits the text with the `<i></i>` tags it will display on the page as `<i>Text submitted</i>`.

Is there a different way, besides `htmlspecialchars()`, to allow other tags but stop the script tags or any other tags people can manipulate?

Or could I use some sort of `text.replace()` to stop script tags but allow others?

Comment: How do I use the HTMLPurifier? It gives me a ton of files that I wouldn't know where to begin with

Comment: You better use regular expression for more safety

Try this one

    $html = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $html);

same as you implemented the `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @aswzen — NO! DEAR GOD NO! That's amazingly and dangerously insufficient.

Comment: @TheWelshManc — It has documentation. Try that? http://htmlpurifier.org/docs#toclink0